# How can I get the row, column clicked in gwt table?

Tags: gwt

I have a flextable that gets populated with data from a database.

I want to get the ROW number of the clicked row.

So far I figured out only how to get the value of a particular cell in a particular row. You have to know the position and hard code it which isn't practical.

```
 String test =flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().getElement(2, 2).getInnerHTML();
 System.out.println(test);
```

How can I create a ClickHandler to get the selected row?

Answer (score 2):

```
//flexTable is a FlexTable object. Add a ClickHandler to it.
flexTable.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {            
            //gets the index of the cell you clicked on
            int cellIndex = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex();
            //gets the index of the row you clicked on
            int rowIndex = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
            //print statements below will verify 
            System.out.println("cellIndex "+cellIndex);
            System.out.println("rowIndex "+rowIndex);
            //gets the value of the selected cell
            String test =flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().getElement(rowIndex,cellIndex ).getInnerHTML();
            System.out.println(test);
                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FlexTable` supports row spans and column spans, allowing you to layout data in a variety of ways. I think you should use `CellTable` or a `DataGrid` or for that matter even a `CellList` if only single column data is being displayed. To these widgets you can add a `selectionhandler` to which you can achieve your goal. Refer [this](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) it has some pre coded examples.